# WebApiConfig.Register is not run

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I had an ASP.NET MVC project* that was created when VS 2013 first came out. (Aside: how do I find out the MVC version used for an existing project?).  I have it now opened in VS 2015 and added a `Web API 2` controller.

A static `WebApiConfig` class was added by VS. However, the `Register` method wasn't called. As a result, my api route is not recognized.

How/where can I call the `WebApiConfig.Register` method and what is the parameter that has to be passed to this method?

---

`*` This is the version where there is an `App_Start` folder with BundleConfig.cs, FilterConfig.cs, IdentityConfig.cs, RouteConfig.cs, StartupAuth.cs, WebApiConfig.cs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated [in this post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2), you should use `GlobalConfiguration.Configure` and not `WebApiConfig.Register` for any new (or migrated) Web API 2 project:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    //MVC Registrations
}
```

Also be sure to update any NuGet Package in your project to the last version.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem.  Both the normal MVC and api routes work nicely.

Comment: Applies to Web API 1.  Web API 2 does not work this way.  If you created project with Visual Studio 2017 or your Web API project uses .NET Core 2, then you probably use Web API 2 and this is not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Global.ascx.cs`

```
using System.Web.Http;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    //other stuff            
    //update: do not use WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

> how do I find out the MVC version used for an existing project?

What MVC does it reference? ie what is the version number of the`System.Web.Mvc` assembly which your web project will reference

Comment: I have just added more information in my question regarding the project type. In my `Application_Start`, `GlobalConfiguration` is not in scope. Where can I find this class or object?

Comment: add `using System.Web.Http;`

Comment: Thanks. If I put `WebApiConfig.Register` before `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`, the browser in debugger mode will just close by itself.  If I reverse the sequence, things seem to be normal, but /api/xx still give a 404. What could still be wrong?  *BTW, my System.Web.Mvc has a `Runtime Version` of v4.0.30319 and a `Version` of 5.2.0.0 as seen in Properties.)

Comment: yes so you are using mvc5. (runtime version is the version of the *framework* itself, ie .NET4 CLR in this case) - re: your 404, pls see my answer on mixing web api and mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371613/exposing-a-few-calls-from-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-site-to-other-rest-clients-wit/34584670#34584670

as per that link `WebApiConfig.Register` shld be before `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` - i'm not sure what you mean by 'close by itself' <-- you should break on Exceptions or figure out why its doing that -

Comment: The browser closed because the server had a 500 error had pushed out `Content-Type:application/xml;` <Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message></Error>